# Italic/Bold font in Sqlite Android

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I m working on app which uses sqlite database . I got sucess to store Strings in various languages and also fetching from database .

But My problem is that **i want to store it in bold or italic style.**

Is it possible ?? If yes then how can i achieve that kind of thing ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Format the strings using html.
When you want to display them use `Html.fromhtml( your string)`
E.g.

```
 String myboldstring = <b>boldy</b>
 textView.setText(Html.fromhtml(myboldstring));
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: You can always add the tags before storing them.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to LazyN's solution I suggest you look at using a standard *[markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)* language for this kind of context (much as **stack overflow** does). There are several advantages:

1. Widely used around the web so your users are likely to understand how to use it.
2. Much more secure in the sense that one cannot inject malicious HTML/javascript; this is very difficult to prevent once you allow any HTML as LazyN suggests
3. Trivial to store/export/import etc as it is all legal text string

Comment: Interesting! How will you display a markdown string on a view?

Comment: LazyN - in my case I have written my own (fairly trivial) Java class to go from markdown to HTML (although I believe various bits of code for this are publicly available). Then in the web context I just use that HTML or in the Android context I use the same logic that you do to dislay HTML in a textview.